# Linq select just one column and down to list

Tags: c#, windows, linq, windows-forms-designer

I created db named DbDelta,
I have table named TblBrands,
I tried to linq Brandname column from TblBrands table ToList().
All Sql connection works correctly but I cannot get List().

I have tried something like that.

```
public override IEnumerable<TblBrand> BrandList()
        {
            return Context.TblBrand.Select(r=> new
            {
                r.BrandName,
            }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors from the code above? If so, you should add them to the question. Presumably `BrandName` is not of type `TblBrand`, yet you've defined the function to return an `IEnumerable<TblBrand>` instead of `IEnumerable<string>` (assuming `BrandName` is a `string`)

Comment: @RufusL I think you missed the `new {`. The code is returning a `List<anonymous>` where the method need to return an `IEnumerable<TblBrand>`.

Comment: @NetMage oh, you're right!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what exactly you want back. If you just want a list of the strings I think something like this...

```
Context.TblBrand.Select(r => r.BrandName).ToList();
```

should give you a list of strings of the brand names as opposed to trying to return an anonymous object.